# How do I declare a variable as global?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to declare a global variable in a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file)

I need to set a variable in a script I'm developing as global. How do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Declare it in the global execution context (not in the scope of a function):

```
var x = "hello";
```

Declare it as an implicit property of the global object (be careful, people may think you've made a mistake and missed the `var`, and this will *throw a reference error in strict mode*, so don't use it):

```
x = "hello";
```

Declare it as an explicit property of the global object:

```
window.x = "hello";
```

Keep in mind that `window` is specific to the browser environment. If you are working with node a global object that is available in all contexts is [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

```
global.x = "hello";
```

Comment: +1 for setting property of global object explicitly.

Comment: `process.x`? Did you mean `global.x`?

Comment: @graystateiscoming - I don't know, I haven't used node much. Someone else edited that in. Looking at the docs, I would agree with you.

Comment: Weird. Yeah, the `process` object is available globally, but it isn't the global object. The global object is `global`, which would be equivalent to using `window` in a browser.

Comment: @graystateiscoming - Thanks, I'll update it. I keep meaning to spend time playing around with node, but never seem to find the time!

Comment: @JamesAllardice—good answer. It might be picky, but the phrase "declare it as an explicit property" should be "assign to it as a property", since assignment is quite different to declaration (e.g. when the property is created). The global object is available in all ECMAScript implementations as `this` in global code, so `var global = this;` or even `var global = global || this` then assigning to `global` should work everywhere, including Node.js.

Comment: @RobG - Thanks. Very good points. I intended to update the answer at some point in the near future with the full details of what's actually going on in all 3 examples from the ES5 spec, so I'll incorporate your suggestions then too.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a variable outside any function:

```
var myGlobalVariable = 42;
```

Just don't go overboard on global variables as it will make your code harder to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<script>
var myGlobal = 2;


function xyz()
{
  //can access myGlobal here
}


</script>
```

Comment: While this is correct, it's a poor practice to declare global variable this way. What is usually recommended is that you explicitly do it with `window.myGlobal = 2;`. It's a lot more clear that you are defining something global and not accidentally leaking something in the global scope.

Comment: @codingbiz I think that your code is correct and isn't a poor practice, so you shouldn't have a -1. Then, you have my +1

Comment: @Oriol I can't see much difference from mine and [Lee Taylor]'s answer but I got -1. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

There's a good article on Javascript scope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) - basically anything defined outside is accessible inside, but not vice versa.