# Is it possible to restrict the sharing of a global variable between only 2 script files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uiwebview, android-webview

I am working on an application that require a js variable to share between 2 or 3 scripts only. Now I am using a global variable to share. Is it possible to restrict the sharing of a global variable between only 2 script files?

Comment: No. Either it is global or not. What do you expect?

Comment: no, there is no kind of access modification in js, the variable is either public or wrapped in a closure

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file

Comment: @Bergi, Actually, I don't want the client apps being able to use this variable because it was only intended to share between scripts.

Comment: @user960567: And how would you distinguish between "client apps" and "scripts"?

Comment: Actually client apps are native android, Iphone and Windows Phone

Comment: Huh? Please tell us more about your environment and what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Bergi, I have lot of script files which somehow needed to talk with each other. it works great. But I don't want the client Iphone which contains (Web UIWebView) and Android which contains WebView, able to call any function.

Comment: @user960567: So you are displaying a website in a `UIWebView`, which contains some external scripts. Now which globals do you have (in the website) that should be access-limited?

Comment: @Bergi, I don't want to go in detail. Because it's a big project with lot of scripts that are dynamically loaded when required. My question is simple.

Comment: @user960567: The answer to your simple question is *No*, as stated in my first comment. So I asked what you actually wanted to do, and why you thought you would need to restrict access to global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. YOu may use namespace instead. eg

```
var a={};
a.b={};
a.b.foo= 'something';
```

Comment: Namespaces do not make anything private.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ravi, take a look at namespacing which may give you a bit more flexibility, check out this post Addy Osmani which provides excellent overview of nested namespaces

http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/