# Value of form input is blank in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

When I try to retrieve text that was entered in a form, the result is blank.

```js
document.getElementById("pass").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  document.getElementById("pass").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});
document.getElementById("pinCode").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  document.getElementById("pinCode").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
var pinCode = document.getElementById("pinCode").value;

function createCookie() {
  window.alert(pass);
}
```

```html
<div id="validation">
  <form id="validationForm">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="pass">Password:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
      <label for="pinCode">4-digit PIN:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="pinCode" name="pinCode" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="createCookie()" />
      <p id="rightorwrong"></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="password.js"></script>
```

When the user enters data in the form and presses submit, the function `createCookie()` is called. I know this works because if I put in `window.alert("test");` in the function, it works. Therefore the problem is in the `pass`.

I tried removing the `value` from `var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;`, but that didn't work either.

For clarification, this is what shows up when I press submit on the form:[image]

I'm stumped, because this is also relatively simple code. (I am on Chrome 84.)

TIA

Comment: `var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;` this sets pass when the page initially loads, so it will be empty, you'll need to update `pass` in your keydown event listener, or retrieve the value inside of `createCookie`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variable not changing on event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120122/global-variable-not-changing-on-event)

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, since it's using JQuery. I would want a strictly JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use value inside the function like that:

```js
document.getElementById("pass").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    document.getElementById("pass").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});
document.getElementById("pinCode").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    document.getElementById("pinCode").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});


function createCookie() {
   var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
   var pinCode = document.getElementById("pinCode").value;
    window.alert(pass); 
      window.alert(pinCode); 
}
```

```html
<div id = "validation">
    <form id = "validationForm">
        <fieldset>
            <label for = "pass">Password:</label><br  />
            <input type = "text" id = "pass" name = "pass"  /><br  />
            <label for = "pinCode">4-digit PIN:</label><br  />
            <input type = "text" id = "pinCode" name = "pinCode"  /><br  />
            <input type = "submit" value="Log In" onclick = "createCookie()"  />
            <p id = "rightorwrong"></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "password.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. However, why? Aren't variables that are defined outside of functions usable inside functions too? Or am I wrong?

Comment: because outside the function catch value on load page, in the function only when you press button.

Comment: Oh, ok that makes sense  Thank you. Will accept answer when allowed.

Comment: No problem :) see you next question.

Answer (score 0):

You should get value when you submit, not when js file is loaded. Also you could listen with onchange function

```
var pass;
function createCookie() {
  pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  window.alert(pass); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the javascript code should be like this

```
document.getElementById("pass").addEventListener("keydown", function () {
    document.getElementById("pass").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";

});
document.getElementById("pinCode").addEventListener("keydown", function () {
    document.getElementById("pinCode").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});


function createCookie() {
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var pinCode = document.getElementById("pinCode").value;
    alert(pass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put your variable inside the function. As initially when page loads, their values will be null and you are not reassigning values to them.**

So, either **change** their values on `keydown` or **set** their values on `click`.

```
function createCookie() {
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var pinCode = document.getElementById("pinCode").value;
  window.alert(pass);
}
```

Check the snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("pass").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  document.getElementById("pass").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});
document.getElementById("pinCode").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  document.getElementById("pinCode").style.backgroundColor = "#DFFEFE";
});

function createCookie() {
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var pinCode = document.getElementById("pinCode").value;
  window.alert(pass);
}
```

```html
<div id="validation">
  <form id="validationForm">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="pass">Password:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
      <label for="pinCode">4-digit PIN:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="pinCode" name="pinCode" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="createCookie()" />
      <p id="rightorwrong"></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="password.js"></script>
```