# addEventListener works only one time

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm pretty new the programming and I'm trying to make Rock paper scissors using Javascript and I ran into this problem. Whenever I click the rock Image, it is supposed to generate a random number between 0 and 2 and if the number is 0, it's a tie, if it's 1, the player loses and if it's 2 the player wins. But when I run this code it only works if the number is 0. So when I click the button, if the number is 0 it shows 'its a tie' but if it isn't 0 it does not show anything. But when I try clicking again, it does not work. I have to refresh the page to try again. Can someone help me, sorry if I didn't explain this properly.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    <title> Rock Paper Scissors! </title>
    <body>
        <div id="rpsGame">
        <h1 id="RPS"> Rock, paper, scissors! </h1>
          <div id="score">
        <p id="myScore">0</p>
        <p>:</p>
        <p id="botScore">0</p>
          </div>
        <img src="rock.png" id="rock">
        <img src="paper.png" id="paper">
        <img src="scissors.png" id="scissors">
        <p id="winOrLose"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
            var rockChoice = document.getElementById('rock');
            var botAnswer = document.getElementById('winOrLose')

         rockChoice.addEventListener('click', function() {
             if (randomNumber == 0) {
                 botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked rock, you tie!"
             
               if (randomNumber == 1) {
                  botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked paper, you lose!"
             

            if (randomNumber == 2) {
                  botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked scissors, you lose!"
             }
         }
    }
         });
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#2a303d;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#rock {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45.8%;
    left: 39.75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
}

#paper {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45.8%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#scissors {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52.05%;
    left: 57.25%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#RPS {
    font-size: 65px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#botPick {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 350px;
}

#Score p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#winOrLose {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: You are nesting your ifs, so code reacts only on first one ===0, there is nothing else to react on, move the others outside of first if, please learn how esle if works: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: oh wow, I'm dumb. I actually did not mean to do that, but thanks. Now the only problem is that I have to refresh the page and click the button again to do it again. If I click it again without refreshing it just wont work.

Comment: Move your declaration of random number inside of click  EventListener before first if, so it generates new random number every time On click, the way you have it now, it generates on load one time and stays like that.

Comment: as side note: read into `switch statement`. In consumes less resourcess then a if statements optimizing the code in your case.

Comment: It also helps to think of things in terms of events instead of data. Think about your program from a 'when this happens, do this' approach instead of 'get everything on the page then react to stuff' approach. You clearly want the random number to trigger *after* something else happens, but it's easy to miss that without the right mindset

Comment: @tacoshy Yeah, i've heard the switch statements are much better thanks!

Comment: @rook218 hmm, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variable not changing on event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120122/global-variable-not-changing-on-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
var rockChoice = document.getElementById('rock');
var botAnswer = document.getElementById('winOrLose')
var botScore = document.getElementById('botScore')

rockChoice.addEventListener('click', function() {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  botScore.innerHTML = randomNumber;
  if (randomNumber == 0) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked rock, you tie!"
  } // close this here
  if (randomNumber == 1) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked paper, you lose!"
  } // and this here

  if (randomNumber == 2) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked scissors, you lose!"
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2a303d;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#rock {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}

#paper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#scissors {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#RPS {
  font-size: 65px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#botPick {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 350px;
}

#Score p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#winOrLose {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<title> Rock Paper Scissors! </title>

<body>
  <div id="rpsGame">
    <h1 id="RPS"> Rock, paper, scissors! </h1>
    <div id="score">
      <p id="myScore">0</p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p id="botScore">0</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIrN1IJ0Q4tKqrKg3f02_PIpFbHHAm-Ri5pA&usqp=CAU" alt="rock" id="rock">
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20201020/ourmid/pngtree-a-torn-note-paper-png-image_2369714.jpg" id="paper">
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190918/ourmid/pngtree-scissors-2764712-png-image_1733940.jpg" id="scissors">
    <p id="winOrLose"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve something like the demo below. See the comments in the js for more details:

```js
var botAnswer = document.getElementById('winOrLose')
var playerScoreEl = document.getElementById('myScore');
var botScoreEl = document.getElementById('botScore');
var choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

//Add a click event listener on the parent element and then check which option was selected by the user by inspecting the `event` argument provided to the handler function
document.getElementById('option-container').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    var playerChoice = event.target.alt;
    var botChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    var playerWonRound = false;
    var isTie = false;

    //Compare the bot choice with the player's choice
    switch (botChoice) {
      case playerChoice:
        isTie = true;
        break;
      case 'Rock':
        if (playerChoice === 'Paper') {
          playerWonRound = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'Paper':
        if (playerChoice === 'Scissors') {
          playerWonRound = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'Scissors':
        if (playerChoice === 'Rock') {
          playerWonRound = true;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (isTie) {
      botAnswer.innerHTML = `Bot picked: ${botChoice} - tie!`;
      return;
    }

    //Update the score on the UI
    if (playerWonRound) {
      playerScoreEl.innerHTML = parseInt(playerScoreEl.innerHTML) + 1;
    } else {
      botScoreEl.innerHTML = parseInt(botScoreEl.innerHTML) + 1;
    }

    //Update the round message on the UI
    botAnswer.innerHTML = `Bot picked: ${botChoice} - you ${playerWonRound ? 'win' : 'lose'}!`;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<title> Rock Paper Scissors! </title>

<body>
  <div id="rpsGame">
    <h1 id="RPS"> Rock, paper, scissors! </h1>
    <div id="score">
      <span id="myScore">0</span>:
      <span id="botScore">0</span>
    </div>
    <div id="option-container">
      <img src="rock.png" id="rock" alt="Rock">
      <img src="paper.png" id="paper" alt="Paper">
      <img src="scissors.png" id="scissors" alt="Scissors">
    </div>
    <p id="winOrLose"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It gave me some time to give to fix your code. please note that I did not make for update the DOM with scores. Instead of using DOM, I use `console.log()`

So please don't forget to check the console in your browser while you testing this code.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

var myScore = 0;
var botScore = 0;

var myScoreElement = document.getElementById("myScore");
var botScoreElement = document.getElementById("botScore");

console.log(randomNumber);

//assign your defalut choose between 0 - 3
var rockChoiceNumber = 0;
var paperChoiceNumber = 1;
var scissorsChoiceNumber = 2;

var rockChoice = document.getElementById("rock");
var paperChoice = document.getElementById("paper");
var scissorsChoice = document.getElementById("scissors");
var botAnswer = document.getElementById("winOrLose");

rockChoice.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rockChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked rock, you tie!";
    myScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  if (paperChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked paper, you lose!";
    botScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  if (scissorsChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked scissors, you lose!";
    botScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
});

paperChoice.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rockChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked rock, you tie!";
    myScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  if (paperChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked paper, you lose!";
    botScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  if (scissorsChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked scissors, you lose!";
    botScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
});

scissorsChoice.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rockChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked rock, you tie!";
    myScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  if (paperChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked paper, you lose!";
    botScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  if (scissorsChoiceNumber == randomNumber) {
    botAnswer.textContent = "Bot picked scissors, you lose!";
    botScore++;
    console.log("My Score: " + myScore);
    console.log("Bot Score: " + botScore);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<title> Rock Paper Scissors! </title>

<body>
  <div id="rpsGame">
    <h1 id="RPS"> Rock, paper, scissors! </h1>

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="rock">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="paper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="scissors">
    <br>
    <div id="score">
      <p id="myScore">0</p>
      :
      <p id="botScore">0</p>
    </div>
    <p id="winOrLose"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please re-read what the question was. It was not about a possible issue with the score. And youa dded tons of JS line that wasnt asked for.