# confusion of javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have been proved I do not truly understand javascript closure, and I am being confused by the following codes. I thought fxn would access the outside foo, but it actually print out "underfined". Why??

```
var foo = "hello";
function fxn(){
   alert(foo);
   var foo = "test"
}

fxn();
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It will log _undefined_ but alert `hello`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because in JavaScript, variables get [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), which means

> Variables are initialised to **undefined** when created. A variable with
>   an *Initialiser* is assigned the value of its *AssignmentExpression* when
>   the *VariableStatement* is **executed**, not when the variable is created.<sub>[(ES5 §12.2)](http://es5.github.io/#x12.2)</sub>

Thus, semantically, your code would be equivalent, to the following...

```
var foo = "hello";
function fxn(){
   var foo; //Variables are initialised to undefined when created
   alert(foo);
   foo = "test"; //A variable with an *Initialiser* is assigned the value of its *AssignmentExpression* when the *VariableStatement* is **executed**
}

fxn();
```

Answer (score 1):

You define your variable `foo` outside your function. If you repeat calls for `var`, you redefine the variable inside the function and it loses its allocation.

Remove `var` in the function to access `foo` into the function `fnx`.

```
var foo = "hello";
function fxn(){
   alert(foo);
   foo = "test";
}

fxn();
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ATea/2/)

Comment: could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: You define your variable "foo" outside your function. If you repeat calls for "var", you redefine the variable inside the function and it loses its allocation.

Comment: I would add to R3tep: 1) redefining the in method hides the external definition, but ... 2) you are using a variable before it is defined => 'undefined' (see also C5H8NNaO4 answer)

Comment: @Hezi For me `foo` is a global variable on this example ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file)). So the variable is defined and after `alert()` is updated.

Comment: @R3tep Correct. But in the original question, the variable was redefined using 'var'.

Comment: @Hezi _I thought fxn would access the outside foo, but it actually print out "underfined"_ Redefined using 'var' is an error for me in this question