# Global vars in prototypes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set and access a global var in a prototype way?

```
var app;

(function(){
    "use strict";
    var App = function() {

    };
    App = App;
}(window));

$(function() {                    
    app = new App();
});
```

Comment: I don't think `App = App` is doing what you think it is. `window.App = App` is probably what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I set a global var?

Comment: By doing just that; `window.yourGlobalVar = theValueYouWantToBeAccessedGlobally`.

Comment: Which variable are trying to set/get access to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in a .js file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file)

Comment: @cookiemonster: Not really willing to cast a duplicate on that, as none of the answers in that question handle the IIFE situation which ***this*** question evolves around.

Comment: @Matt: IIFE is irrelevant. It doesn't change the way to create a global from within a function. Main thing is that OP needs to search before asking. This question has been asked [many timnes](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+create+global++variable+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gws_rd=ssl), which is no surprise since creating a global variable is not uncommon.

Comment: It sure does in strict mode, usually just omitting the `var` keyword creates a global in another scope, here it wouldn't, but of course attaching it as a property to the window would always work, so it's sort of a duplicate as the most upvoted answer in that question would work here as well, but it's not really the same question ?

Comment: @cookiemonster: It does. You can pass in the global object to the IIFE, and reference it using the parameter name, just a adeneo used in his answer. That technique isn't explained anywhere in your dupe, which is quite a crucial omission. I'm not saying there's not a dupe of this, I'm saying the question you linked to isn't it.

Comment: @Matt: You can do that in any function, or not pass it at all. Doesn't matter. The way to create a global doesn't change. He's asking how to create a global, and it has been answered in the dupe I posted.

Comment: @cookiemonster: ... and where is that behavior explained in the duplicate you proposed? It's **not** a dupe, but I'll reiterate what I said before; I'm not saying there's not a dupe of this, I'm saying the question you linked to isn't it. Hopefully other community members will see sense and not cast votes against that either. /o

Comment: What behavior? You can create a global by adding a property to the `window` object, as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/944373/3096782) shows. You're making little sense.

Comment: @adeneo: Creating globals by omitting `var` is just bad practice IMO. The property way is to add properties to the global object as your answer and some answers in other question shows. Given that, strict mode won't make a difference. I do think it's the same. At least I fail to see how it differs in any substantial way.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using strict mode, the value of `this` inside the IIFE isn't window, it's probably `undefined`, so `App` isn't really global.

If you explicitly make it global it should work

```
var app;

(function (w) {
    "use strict";

    w.App = function () {

    };

}(window));

$(function () {
    app = new App();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVz5K/1/)

If you weren't using strict mode, you could just remove the `var` keyword

Comment: To clean up, you either probably want to stop `window` being passed to the IIFE, or give a name to the parameter.

Comment: @Matt - doesn't really matter, but sure, lets use the argument !

Comment: I agree it didn't break anything, but it was likely confusing/ misleading for people new to the concept.