# Two Javascript files included on site with same variable names

Tags: javascript

I have a site with multiple Javascript files included. Two of the JS files have the following variable:

`var $gridName`

Will this cause any conflicts for me in my site? For example, will the value of `$gridName` be set by the last JS file that got included or some other type of unwanted behavior?

Here is the top of one of my files, where the variable is declared:

```
$(function () {
    var intlastRowId;
    var strAppName = 'allocation-details';
    var $gridName = $("#grid-allocation-details");
```

Comment: Does either script use a namespace? If not, then yes, there will be a conflict.

Comment: @j08691 No, no namespaces are used.

Comment: The all-important question is: Are these *global* variables? If so, your scripts are likely going to clobber each other's state. If not, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @meagar no, I do not believe they are global... They are declared as you see above: `var $gridName = "";`

Comment: @FastTrack using `var` doesn't make it not global in all cases. If you're executing code directly in the global scope, `var x` will still result in a global variable.

Comment: @KevinB see my edit above... would you say those variables have been declared in the global scope?

Comment: No, those are not in the global scope, and therefore will not conflict.

Comment: @KevinB ok, good, that was my intention! So being this is the way they are declared, these should not cause any conflict issues between one another. Is that correct?

Comment: @KevinB when I replied to your comment, you hadn't edited it yet. So all I saw was "No, those are not in the global scope."

Comment: Sorry, i have a bad habit of posting and editing, so much so that i often forget that i even do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes same variable named may give conflicts i.e one value can overwrite other it depends on few things like are those variables global or local.

Comment: These are not global variables.. They are declared as such: `var $gridName = "";`

Comment: @FastTrack Are they declared in the global scope? If so, they're global - it doesn't matter if they have `var` or not in that case

Comment: Pls check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file

Comment: Declaring variables with var doesn't make it local.if variable is declared with var inside scope of a function , then they are local to it.in your case if it's local than it should not crete issues and it depends also on which js is included before.

Comment: @jai check my edit above... I show you where I declare my vars

Comment: Sorry @FastTrack , my mistake as it's in scope it should not create issues. Is it creating?

Comment: No, it's not creating any issues, but the thought crossed my mind that it might, so I just wanted to verify if it would cause me problems or not. Thanks for the help