# How to use react components from other files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, components, reactjs

I have a simple reactJS component like this :

```
var LikeCon = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <span>Like</span>
        );
    }
});
```

This is placed in a file called Common.jsx. Im trying to use this LinkeCon component from antoher jsx file like this

```
var FeedTopic = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var test = false;
            return (
                <div className="topic">
                        {LikeCon}
                </div>

            );
        }
});
```

The problem is that this exception is thrown

> Error while rendering "FeedBox" to "react1": ReferenceError: LikeCon
>   is not defined

This is how the import looks like on the Layoutpage

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common.jsx")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Grid.jsx")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Feed.jsx")"></script>
```

My thought was that if Common.jsx that contains the shared component was first, then the var would also be available to the other react components?

Edit :

this is placed on the Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JSXTransformer.js")"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common.jsx")"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Grid.jsx")"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Feed.jsx")"></script>
```

The component is now refered to with `<LikeCon like="0" />` instead of `{LikeCon}`.

Edit 2 :

This is how I use the LikeCon

```
var TopicComments = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var comment = this.props.data.map(function(com, i) {
            return (
            <article key={i}>
            <div className="commentCon">
                <div className="tUImgLnk">
                    <a title={com.UserName} target="_blank" href={com.UserInfoUrl}>
                        <img className="tUImg" src={com.UserPicSrc} />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <b><a href="#" title={"Visit " + com.UserName} target="_blank">{com.UserName}</a></b>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
                <span className="content">
                    {com.Message}
                </span>
                <div className="status">
                    <div className="dateCreated dimText">
                        {com.DateCreated}
                    </div>  
                    <LikeCon initialLike={com.Like} initialLikeCount={com.LikeCount} objectId={com.Id} categoryKey={1} userId={this.props.userId} />
                    <article></article>
                </div>
            </div>
            </article>);
        }.bind(this));
        return(
            <div className="comments">
                {comment}
            </div>
            );
    }
});
```

This is how the script import looks like

```
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autosize.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/spin.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JSXTransformer.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Grid.jsx")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Feed.jsx")"></script>
    @RenderSection("ScriptFoot", required: false)
    @Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
</body>
```

This is the exception I get :

> Error while rendering "FeedBox" to "react1": ReferenceError: LikeCon
>   is not defined    at React.createClass.render (Script Document
>   [7]:83:33) ->         React.createElement(LikeCon, {initialLike:
>   this.props.data.Like, i    at Script Document [2]:7021:34    at
>   wrapper (Script Document [2]:12893:21)    at Script Document
>   [2]:6563:14    at wrapper (Script Document [2]:12893:21)    at
>   ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (Script Document [2]:12352:42)
>   at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (Script Document
>   [2]:7801:32)    at Script Document [2]:7723:14    at wrapper (Script
>   Document [2]:12893:21)    at Script Document [2]:6569:44    at wrapper
>   (Script Document [2]:12893:21)    at Script Document [2]:6569:44    at
>   wrapper (Script Document [2]:12893:21)    at Script Document
>   [2]:13797:38    at Mixin.perform (Script Document [2]:16855:20)    at
>   renderToString (Script Document [2]:13795:24)    at Script Document
>   [9] [temp]:1:7 Line: 7021 Column:34

Comment: Instead of using var did you try to define it on the global scope like `window.LikeCon` and see if works?

Comment: I will try that but why could not var work as global? According to this it should : http://stackoverflow.com/a/944288/365624

Comment: I tried this : window.LikeCon = React.createClass.. and then  {window.LikeCon} in the other jsx file but it complains about  windows not define?

Comment: `windows` doesn't exist, you should use `window.LikeCon`.

Comment: Sorry, its window.LikeCon Im using, miss type.

Comment: What's compiling your `jsx` files (as that file wouldn't normally be compilable by the browser using just a plain `script` tag as you've shown)? Are they being wrapped in a closure of some sort and preventing them from having a common scope?

Comment: Im using ReactJS.NET with V8 engine, would that be a problem? It is supose to be rendered serverside.

Comment: The second edit doesn't show _Scripts/Common.jsx_ being loaded. If that is really so then obviously `LikeCon` definition is not available to the subsequent components :) Or if you're including it before the shown snippet that would still mean it's not getting transpiled because _JSXTransformer.js_ is loading later. I suspect you're getting mixed up in loading different js and jsx files via different layouts/templates. For simplicity, load all of them only from the template in question and see?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add: `<script src="Scripts/JSXTransformer.js"></script>`
2. Instead of `{LikeCon}` use `<LikeCon/>`
3. Use `type="text/jsx"` in your scripts

Comment: JSXTransformer.js is a regular javascript file so it should not have the type "text/jsx"

Comment: Sorry, still not working, see Edit 2 in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you export your `LikeCon` component, and import it in the file you want to use it in.

```
var LikeCon = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <span>Like</span>
        );
    }
});
```

should be:

```
class LikeCon extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return 
            <span>Like</span>
        );
    }
}

export default LikeCon
```

Then on whatever file(s) you wanted to use `LikeCon` component include this at the top of your file:

`import LikeCon from'./path/to/LikeCon.jsx;`

Note: my answer is using ES2016...syntax is a tad different.