# Accessing variable from different function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in HTML which creates a button, that when clicked creates some questions in my page, works fine.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="num_questions" min="1" max="99"><br>
<input type="button" name="go" id="go_button" value="Go" onclick="createQuestions()"><br>
```

However, within my function `createQuestions()` I have defined a variable in JavaScript, which is based on a number input from my HTML code, shown above.

```
var number = document.getElementById('num_questions').value;
```

I have another button which calls a separate function but I *need* that variable number I locally defined in another function.  Is there any way I can grab that variable and use it globally?  I tried defining it outside my function, but since the onclick event only calls that one function, it won't create the variable.

Other button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Tree" onclick="displayData()">
```

Comment: You should be able to access the `number` variable anywhere if you define it globally. The when you run your `createQuestions()` function you can assign it to a value. Can you post the rest of your JS here? It would be helpful to fully solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How to declare a global variable in a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file) you can define a variable before any function is called and then use it in different functions.

```
var global1 = "I'm a global!";

function setGlobal () {
    global1= document.getElementById('num_questions').value;
}
function testGlobal () {
    alert(global1);
}
```

Comment: But when I call that function setGlobal() on a button click, the variable will not be declared, since the button click is calling ONLY the function..

Comment: You may not declare it inside the function, but you can reassign the variable. And it will be accessible, because it is global.

Comment: Aha!  There we go, this is exactly what I needed.  I wonder why I never thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access a function's local variables from outside of that function, so you have four options:

1. Declare a global variable!
2. Write a separate function that grabs the value for you
3. Create an object that contains the value you need
4. Grab the value from within your new function using `getElementById()`