# Why is the global variable covered by the variable in the function?

Tags: javascript

I have defined a variable `myData` outside a function and I try to assign the data which I get from axios to the variable `myData`, but failed. The variable `shareData` has the right value -- `response.data` inside the function -- but the value of it turned to the original one when exiting the function.

It must be the local variable covers the outer one, so how do you avoid this and let the outer variable get the `response.data` value?

```
var shareData = 'OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION'

axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/api/usershare', //API
    responseType: 'json',
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    shareData = response.data
    console.log(shareData) //output the reponse.data correctly
  })
console.log(shareData) //output OUTSIDE TEH FUNCTION, which is the orignal value of myData
```

Comment: More like why is an asynchronous function not acting like it is synchronous. You order a delivery pizza and as soon as you click submit on the order form you try to eat the pizza.

Comment: Try this my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885012/call-a-global-variable-into-two-functions-using-javascript/46885947?noredirect=1#comment80729697_46885947

Comment: use `promise` or `setTimeout` instead.because this is asynchronous code it will execute last `console` it won't `wait` for your `axios request` to complete

Comment: @ashishyadav : Promise is best setTimeout fails many times or unnecessary waste of time.

Comment: @user2486 you are absolutely right. I was just giving lucasFang a quick explanation and solution