# How to access an object from another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm trying to get some data from an array and store store it in an object but I keep getting either an empty object or `Promise { <pending> }` in the logs. I'm using a `global` variable to store it and access it in another function. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
var messageData = {};

const getNotifications =  async () => {
    let fcmObjects = await fcmTokens();
    fcmObjects.forEach( (notificationData) => {
        messageData = notificationData;
    });
};

function getMessageData() {
    console.log(messageData);
}

getMessageData();

getNotifications().then(function () {
    console.log('All Done');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Oops', error);
});
```

Comment: messageData = notificationData;

seems you exactly setting some value into variable.. ensure its is object... 
or set my,
messageData['key'] = value

Comment: checkout my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

the console log is happening before the async method/Promise is being resolved. You should check it only after that. In other words, your code should be similar to:

```
getNotifications().then(function () {
    getMessageData();
    console.log('All Done');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Oops', error);
});
```

If you do not want to call it inside `getNotifications()`, just get the Promise it returns and execute your call inside the `.then()` (option 1) or do an `await` (option 2). In code:

```
const notificationPromise = getNotifications();
// option 1
notificationPromise.then(getMessageData);
// option 2
await notificationPromise;
getMessageData();
```

A link to know more https://javascript.info/async about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Decoding your program line by line

```
var messageData = {};
```

is an object

```
const getNotifications =  async () => {
    let fcmObjects = await fcmTokens();
    fcmObjects.forEach( (notificationData) => {
        messageData = notificationData;
    });
};
```

`getNotifications` is an async function.

```
function getMessageData() {
    console.log(messageData);
}
```

`getMessageData` prints whatever is message data.

```
getMessageData();
```

you printed message data which is `{}`. Remember `getNotfications` is never called till now as the line are executed one by one.

```
getNotifications().then(function () {
    console.log('All Done');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Oops', error);
});
```

Now the above code call `getNotification` and run the `function` provided in `then` when the async call is completed. So you need to call `getMessageData()` in then function.

```
getNotifications().then(function () {
    getMessageData();
    console.log('All Done');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Oops', error);
});
```

Comment: I just want to use `messageData` in some other function. I don't wanna called the 'getNotifications()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944273/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-js-file
Check this out.. I think you can use message data where ever you want in .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You execute `getMessageData` before `getNotifications`. You can use async/await approach

```
try {
  await getNotifications();
  getMessageData();
  console.log('All Done');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Oops', error);
}
```

```js
var messageData = [];

const getNotifications = async() => {
  //let fcmObjects = await fcmTokens();
  //fcmObjects.forEach((notificationData) => {
  //  messageData = notificationData;
  //});
  
  // simulate commentet above code
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ messageData=['someMessage']; resolve()})
};

function getMessageData() {
    console.log(messageData);
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await getNotifications();
    getMessageData();
    console.log('All Done');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Oops', error);
  }
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait the getNotifications function to finish before you could log it's result to the console.

getNotifications is asynchronous, which means it won't run synchronously and the following lines of code

```js
function getMessageData() {
    console.log(messageData);
}

getMessageData();
```

may be executed before your getNotifications completes, thus your getMessageData() call doesn't print the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

First: your global variable `messageData` gonna be the last item in `fcmObjects` in this scenario. so make sure you provide a key or index for `messageData` object in `fcmObjects.forEach( (notificationData) => {
        messageData = notificationData;
    });`

Second:
when you call an [Asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) operation you would not log it that way.

After all your code must be like this:

```
var messageData = {};

const getNotifications =  async () => {
    let fcmObjects = await fcmTokens();
    fcmObjects.forEach( (index, notificationData) => {
        messageData[index] = notificationData;
    });
};

function getMessageData() {
    console.log(messageData);
}

getNotifications().then(function () {
    getMessageData();
    console.log('All Done');
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Oops', error);
});
```